# How do I make it so when I click a button my image changes?

Tags: javascript, image, function

I tried to create a function where when the button is clicked the source of the image changed, but it didn't work.

```
<img
   class="bowgart"
   id="bowgart"
   src="C:\Users\jbrir\Documents\BowgartWebsite2\images\bowgart.png"
   alt="Bowgart"
/>
<script>
   function imgOpen() {
      document.getElementById("bowgart").src = "C:UsersjbrirDocumentsBowgartWebsite2imagesBowgart_open.jpeg";
   }
</script>
```

Comment: This is the button script that goes at the top. I accidently didn't include it.                     <button class="open" type="open" onclick="imgOpen()">Open mouth</button>

Comment: Don't you see the "Edit" button below the question? Use that when you accidentally left something out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `src` needs to be a valid URL. You're missing the `file:` URL scheme and all the `/` delimiters in the pathname.

```
function imgOpen() {
  document.getElementById("bowgart").src =
    "file:///C:/Users/jbrir/Documents/Bowgart/Website2/images/Bowgart_open.jpeg";
}
```

Comment: I forgot to link the script sheet to the index XD

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulbon.gif'">Turn on the light</button>

<img id="myImage" src="pic_bulboff.gif" style="width:100px">

<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulboff.gif'">Turn off the light</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The way how this code works is that when you click the button it changes the source of the image(you do have to have both images) and applies that to the image. And if that was confusing to you then here is a simpler way of saying that: if the image was off and you click the 'on' button it will change to image to on else it does not do anything and the same if it was on. And this is just an example so apply this to your images.